# Multiple TWS Agents in one server

Tags: workload-scheduler

Having existing FT Agent and testing out z-Centric Agent on the same server. Understand that we can only have 1 agent instance per userid. Is there any other work-around available to use a single user-id for 2 Agents, as security will take some period of time to define a new userid (on Lunix-X86)..

Answer (score 0):

FTA installation also installs Dynamic Agent that can be used also as zCentric agent.

So, just configure and start the zCentric agent you already have without installing a separate one with a separate userid.

Comment: Just to clarify, that we configure the existing FTA as Dynamic Agent then start as zCentric. This will mean we will have to change the Workstation definition on TWSz from FTA to zCentric. Would there be any impact to existing definitions for jobs that are currently defined to run on the Workstation when it was FTA?

Comment: The same agent installation can have FTA an Dynamic Agent running at the same time.
You can use the dynamic agent part, just for zCentric and not change any workstation on TWSd.
If you want you can also have an additional workstation on TWSd for the dynamic agent, but this is not required if you only need FTA & zCentric.

To summarize, you can use a single agent installation to have at the same time:
- 1 FTA (or DM, or SA)
- 1 Dynamic agent
- zCentric agent for multiple TWSz controllers

Comment: Thanks a lot Franco, will go ahead and configure the existing as having both FTA and zCentric

Comment: Franco, have been looking for documentation on how to set-up a single agent install for 2 runtime instances (FTA and zCentric) but could not locate such a document. All documents we find talk about install of agent and configure to generate 1 runtime instance. Could you send a link or document that will assist in configuring a second runtime instance of the agent?